# Keep a fixed number of files in a directory

Tags: linux, shell-script

We have a Linux directory where files and directories are being added to it daily.

We like to control this list of files and subdirectories in the directory by fixing the list to 50 most recent files and directories at any given time.

How do we write a script to achieve this goal?

Comment: What does "fixing the list to 50 most recent files" mean, exactly?

Comment: Do you want to list the 50 most resent files? Or delete all files older than that?

Comment: Hi Ярослав Рахматуллин, slhck, thanks for responding. We like to keep the most recent 50 subdirectories of a directory.

Comment: @chz do you mean that you want to delete all directories except for the 50 most recently created ones?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `find` and `sort`, this gets you the 50 latest files and their timestamp from the current directory:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -n 50
```

Pipe these into `while read` to get each filename:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%T@ %p\n' |
sort -n | tail -n 50 |
while read -r ts file; do echo rm -rf -- "$file"; done
```

Here, `printf` outputs a sortable timestamp, which the numeric `sort` will use. We get the oldest 50 files or directories and remove each one individually. Remove the `echo` in the script to actually execute the commands.

Note that this does not work if your files/directories contain a newline in their name. Doesn't happen that often, but be careful to check. Due to the nature of `read`, it will also not work if there are leading or trailing spaces.

For some more ideas, see: [BashFAQ/003 – How can I find the latest (newest, earliest, oldest) file in a directory?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003)

Comment: The question was how to keep the newest 50 files, not how to remove 50 oldest ones...

Answer (score -3):

If you need to look only at the dirs in the folder (not for subdir) then execute the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
l=$(ls |wc -l)
n=$[$l-50]
rm -rf `ls -1t|tail -$n`
```

Comment: Please carefully read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs — the output of `ls` shouldn't be parsed. This **will** cause problems with files containing spaces in their path. Your script is therefore not safe. Also, for the future, please check our formatting help and indent code by 4 spaces.